# Calculating mean across all dimensions of a tensor except nth dimension

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch

I have a torch tensor of dimension `[7, 12, 12, 197, 197]`. I would like to calculate mean such that resultant vector is of shape `[7,1,1,197,1]`. Is there any other way rather than using a `for loop`? Could you provide answer with benchmark on execution time?

Comment: This sounds like a code request rather than help debugging. Especially that last sentence.

Comment: This question can be improved by sharing what you've tried.

Comment: And by providing a [mre].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Torch provides `mean` along with `dim` as argument. This `dim` can take tuple of integers.

```
import torch
tensor = torch.randn(4, 5, 6, 7)

dims_to_reduce = (1,3)
means = torch.mean(tensor, dim=dims_to_reduce, keepdim=True)
print(means.shape)
>>torch.Size([4, 1, 6, 1])
```

Answer (score 1):

With [numpy](/questions/tagged/numpy) you can use [`mean`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.mean.html) with a tuple of the dimensions/axes to use for the aggregation, and `keepdims=True` to retain the shape:

```
out = arr.mean((1,2,4), keepdims=True)
```

Example:

```
np.random.seed(0)
arr = np.random.random((7, 12, 12, 197, 197))
print(arr.shape)

out = arr.mean((1,2,4), keepdims=True)
print(out.shape)
```

Output:

```
(7, 12, 12, 197, 197)
(7, 1, 1, 197, 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple method by using torch.mean , please check if it works.

```
import torch

tensor = torch.randn(4, 5, 6, 7)  # Example tensor
nth_dim = 2  # Dimension to keep

means = torch.mean(tensor, dim=torch.arange(tensor.ndim) != nth_dim)
print(means.shape)  # Output: torch.Size([4, 6, 7])
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using the `mean` function and telling it which axes to perform the mean over and that the dimensions should be maintained. The code in pytorch is very similar to the code in numpy except `axis` is replaced with `dim` and `keepdims` is replaced with `keepdim`.

```py
import torch

a = torch.rand(7, 12, 12, 197, 197)
print(a.shape)  # torch.Size([7, 12, 12, 197, 197])
b = torch.mean(a, dim=(1,2,4), keepdim=True)
print(b.shape)  # torch.Size([7, 1, 1, 197, 1])
```

and in numpy

```py
import numpy as np

rng = np.random.default_rng(42)
a = rng.random((7, 12, 12, 197, 197))
print(a.shape)  # (7, 12, 12, 197, 197)
b = np.mean(a, axis=(1,2,4), keepdims=True)
print(b.shape)  # (7, 1, 1, 197, 1)
```